# Why isn't xs:precisionDecimal part of the XSD1.1?

Tags: xml, xsd, decimal, precision, xsd-1.1

Although it is stated everywhere that `xs:precisionDecimal` belongs to the XML Schema 1.1 (see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml11pt1/ or https://www.w3.org/TR/xsd-precisionDecimal/), I cannot find any definition for `xs:precisionDecimal` under https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. If I'm clicking on the links under the `XML Schema` section, they are definitions for a lot of types (like int, double, string etc.) but not for precisionDecimal.

Where can I find the definition for `xs:precisionDecimal` and why is not part of https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of the linked IBM DeveloperWorks article (2008), `xs:precisionDecimal` was planned for XSD 1.1 and was in the [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1, W3C Working Draft 20 June 2008](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-xmlschema11-2-20080620/#precisionDecimal).

By [W3C Candidate Recommendation 21 July 2011](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-xmlschema11-2-20110721/), `xs:precisionDecimal` was removed:

> The `precisionDecimal` datatype has been removed since there does not seem to be sufficient consensus in the community for its retention.

It is, as you've observed, not part of the current recommendation, [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes, W3C Recommendation 5 April 2012](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/).

Answer (score 4):

The feature was present in drafts of XSD 1.1, but was pulled at a fairly late stage.

I was active in the working group when this decision was made. The matter became fairly heated, with IBM strongly advocating addition of precisionDecimal, and Oracle strongly opposing it (most of the others didn't really feel strongly either way); but as often happens in standards work, I think the positions were based more on the technical judgements of individuals than on the business interests of corporations.

I personally argued against adding `xs:precisionDecimal` on the grounds that it would fall on the XQuery and XSLT working groups to define the operational semantics (specifically, the rules for arithmetic), which was likely to be a lot more work than just defining the data type for validation purposes. There was also an issue of cyclic dependencies: since XSD 1.1 assertions use XPath, it was difficult to add a new primitive data type to XSD without simultaneously defining XPath operational semantics for that data type; that gave the XQuery and XSLT working groups leverage over the decision, and no-one on the XQuery and XSLT working groups was keen on doing the work. (Don Chamberlin of IBM wrote an outline of what changes would be needed at https://www.w3.org/XML/2007/dc.pd.html; but he retired from both IBM and the working groups fairly soon afterwards)

In the end the decision to pull it from the specs was on the basis that adding a feature to a W3C spec requires a high level of consensus, not just a 50% majority.

Comment: Thanks for relaying the inside story regarding `xs:precisionDecimal`'s late removal.